# Wristband or gloves with programmable buttons?

Tags: usb, remote-control, wearable-technology

Preferably one that is wireless and connects via a small usb dongle.

Think of a gaming mouse. It has programmable buttons - you can program macros.

Say you're using a windows 10 or 8.1 tablet. And say your specific tablet stylus does not have programmable buttons.

What is your best bet?

Comment: That probably rules out the [Power Glove](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AacoxHFYvZw).
Are you doing illustration or note-taking and wish you had some programmable hotkeys?
Would something like [this case with embedded hotkeys](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/gadgetek/meta-the-microcontroller-enhanced-tablet-accessory) have worked for you if the product hadn't failed?

Comment: How many buttons do you require? Did you consider a wristwatch with touch screen? Not much surface area, but still ... plus, gestures